# Running redshift on Debian returns a “Segmentation fault”

Tags: debian, segmentation-fault, redshift

```
$ /usr/bin/redshift -l 52.3:16.3 -t 6700:3500
Segmentation fault


DISTRIB_CODENAME=rodete
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Debian GNU/Linux rodete"
DISTRIB_ID=Debian
DISTRIB_RELEASE=rodete
```

I restart my machine and I saw a popup with `cannot run redshift`.

I tried to run it from the cmd, and got the above `Segmentation fault` error.

Comment: What's `rodete`? That's not a suite we [Debian] publish.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the packages and reinstall from source:

```
mkdir ~/src
cd src
git clone https://github.com/jonls/redshift
cd redshift
./bootstrap
./configure
make -j8
sudo make install
```

then start with

```
/usr/local/bin/redshift
```